# Sinon/Mocha test with async ajax calls didn't return promises

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm writing some test for my client side api use `karma` with `Mocha` and `Sino`. But I'm stuck on getting the async process.

```
import api from '../../../src/api';
import stubData from '../data';
import axios from 'axios';

/* eslint-disable prefer-arrow-callback,func-names */
describe('API test', function () {
  before(function () {
    this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  });
  after(function () {
     this.server.restore();
  });

it('Should return cart with provided token', function (done) {
  this.server.respondWith("GET", "/cart",
        [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
         '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]']);

 axios.get('/cart')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    done();
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    done();
  });
  this.server.respond();
});

 });
```

for some reason, I always getting `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.` from `Mocha`. Seems like the `then` after `axios.get()` is not executed thus `done` is not called either.

I did follow what was recommended in `Mocha` document

```
describe('User', function() {
  describe('#save()', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done) {
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) done(err);
        else done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is an [open issue on sinon](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/885) saying it doesn't work with axios, which seems to be the case here.

Axios is not actually calling your fakeserver. It seems to be trying to request `/cart` literally, that is why you get a timeout.

That user replaced the fakeServer with [another lib called nock](https://github.com/srph/axios-response-logger/commit/5a555bf7fab07c9fff5fe94f9ebbe9a973259cc9) he [mentions it here](https://github.com/srph/axios-response-logger/issues/1)

There are other libs that allow you to mock requests.

I usually use [supertest npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest), [Github](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest).

Example from Github README

```
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'tobi' });
});

request(app)
  .get('/user')
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect('Content-Length', '15')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

Comment: The issue was very helpful, spend couple hours. But at least now I know I'm not stupid... hah

Comment: @IanZhao also they mentioned on that issue that axios has a lib called `moxios` to mock requests https://github.com/mzabriskie/moxios

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the sinon stub only works with axios Request method aliases.
That is if you are using axios by passing config

```
axios(someConfig)
```

The above method doesn't seem to work.

But with method aliases, it seems to work.

```
axios.get(url, params, config)
axios.post(url, data, config)
```

When we do

```
sandbox.stub(axios, "get")
```

I think it is stubbing the method `get` in axios, but in the first case, the `get/post/anyother` method is not called and stubbing doesn't work. I maybe wrong in this. But it is working for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested by @bring2dip is correct, but in case you don't have option other than using

`axios(config)`

then you can use

`axios.request(config)`

and in test.ts you can use

`sandbox.stub(axios, "request")`

and the result will be the same.