# Sinon fakeServer with mocha and axios

Tags: mocha.js, sinon, axios

I'm trying to get sinon.fakeServer to make axios return a faked response. Instead of returning the mocked payload, I can see the network request 404s or does a timeout trying to go to the actual URL.

My setup:

```
  describe('test call', () => {
    var server;
    beforeEach(() => {
      server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
      server.respondWith(
        "https://my.domain.com/myresource",
        [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, "[]"]
      );
      server.autoRespond = true
    });
    it('returns empty array', done => {
      axios
        .get('https://my.domain.com/myresource')
        .then(res => {
          expect(true).to.equal(true);
          done()
        })
        .catch(err=>{
          console.log(err.message);
          expect(false).to.equal(true);
          done();
        });
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      server.restore();
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your execution environment is NodeJS, even though it's not mentioned.  Others had the same issue - have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516044/sinon-mocha-test-with-async-ajax-calls-didnt-return-promises).

Also the Sinon team mentions that it's [outside their scope](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/885) since XHR are supposed to work correctly in the browser, where their fake server works as expected as it stubs the XHR object.

Axios is using a different library for making requests when running on the server, so this scenario cannot work by default.  There are specific mocking libs for **axios** like [moxios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/moxios) as an alternative.